# Slim PHP: How to POST or PUT based on user id?

Tags: php, slim

How can I make an edit API to edit student details in the database after they login into the system without they need to enter their id again?

Below are my login route

```
$app->post('/login', function ($request, $response) {

    $input = $request->getParsedBody();
    $sql = "SELECT id, password FROM users WHERE id= :id";
    $sth = $this->db->prepare($sql);
    $sth->bindParam("id", $input['id']);
    $sth->execute();
    $user = $sth->fetchObject();

    // verify email address 
    if(!$user) {
    return $this->response->withJson(['error' => true, 'message' => 'NO ID '], 404);
    }
   // Compare the input password and the password from database for a validation
    if (strcmp($input['password'],$user->password)) {
        return $this->response->withJson(['error' => true, 'message' => 'These credentials do not match our records.'], 404)->withHeader('Content-type', 'application/json;charset=utf-8', 404);  
    }

    return $this->response->withJson($input)->withStatus(200)->withHeader('Content-type', 'application/json;charset=utf-8', 200);
});
```

// This is the new one that i have tried before but getting failed

```
$app->put('/address', function ($request, $response) {
if (session_status() === PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
    session_start();
}

if(empty($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
    return $response->withJson(['error' => true, 'message' => 'Login please'], 403);
}

$input = $request->getParsedBody();
$sql = "INSERT INTO address (id, s_pNumber, s_address, s_pCode, s_city, s_state, s_country) VALUES 
        (:s_pNumber, :s_address, :s_pCode, :s_city, :s_state, :s_country) WHERE 'user_id' = :id;";
$sth = $this->db->prepare($sql);
$sth->bindParam("s_pNumber", $input['s_pNumber']);
$sth->bindParam("s_address", $input['s_address']);
$sth->bindParam("s_pCode", $input['s_pCode']);
$sth->bindParam("s_city", $input['s_city']);
$sth->bindParam("s_state", $input['s_state']);
$sth->bindParam("s_country", $input['s_country']);
$sth->execute();

return $response->withJson($input)->withStatus(200)->withHeader('Content-type', 'application/json;charset=utf-8', 200);
```

});

Is it correct how i should do? Even when i already try to put session_destory() to test the code but it will always return true

Comment: are you storing plain text passwords?

Comment: yeah, did not implement any encryption yet. Is it different if using any encryption and plain text password?

Comment: Neither is good! Store only hashes.

Comment: **Never store passwords in clear text!** Only store password hashes. Use PHP's [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) . If you're running a PHP version lower than 5.5 (which I really hope you aren't), you can use the [password_compat](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) library to get the same functionality.

Comment: yeah i know, i am a student currently still learning. i'll implement a security component after i already done with the basic one. Thank you for advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neverever use plain passwords in production. But this is not what you were asking for.. If your user login, you can save this information in SESSION for example `$_SESSION['logged_id'] = $input['id']`.

In next request you can check this SESSION to get logged in user by the id.

```
$app->post('/login', function ($request, $response) {

    $input = $request->getParsedBody();
    $sql   = "SELECT id, password FROM users WHERE id= :id";
    $sth   = $this->db->prepare($sql);
    $sth->bindParam("id", $input['id']);
    $sth->execute();
    $user = $sth->fetchObject();

    // verify email address
    if (!$user) {
        return $this->response->withJson(['error' => true, 'message' => 'NO ID '], 404);
    }

    // Compare the input password and the password from database for a validation
    if (strcmp($input['password'], $user->password)) {
        return $this->response->withJson(['error' => true, 'message' => 'These credentials do not match our records.'], 404)->withHeader('Content-type', 'application/json;charset=utf-8', 404);
    }

    if (session_status() === PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
        session_start();
    }

    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $input['id'];

    return $this->response->withJson($input)->withStatus(200)->withHeader('Content-type', 'application/json;charset=utf-8', 200);
});

$app->get('/my-route-only-for-logged-users', function ($request, $response) {
    if (session_status() === PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
        session_start();
    }

    if (empty($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
        return $response->withJson(['error' => true, 'message' => 'Login please'], 403);
    }

    // Now you can get information for certain user, because you know his ID from session...

    return $response
        ->withJson('{"user_id": ' . $_SESSION['user_id'] . '}')
        ->withStatus(200)
        ->withHeader('Content-type', 'application/json;charset=utf-8', 200);
});
```

Comment: any simple code that you can guide me on so that i can understand more or any oher example?

Comment: I've updated my answer. Its not tested, but it can help you to understand my proposal.

Comment: alright thank you, i will try later and i will let you know after i have try

Comment: so how was my sql looks like? i already edited my code that i have already tried

Comment: Not sure, what you are asking... What does return true? Be more specific

Comment: just ignore. My question is, is it my SQL statement is correct that i should be doing?